# Find the sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{20}\frac{(n^2-1/2)}{(n^4+1/4)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, telescopic-series

Hint: this is a telescoping series sum (I have no prior knowledge of partial fraction decomposition)

Attempt: I tried to complete the square but the numerator had an unsimplifiable term. So I couldn't find a pattern. I just need a hint on how to convert this into a telescoping series.

Comment: Recall Sophie Germain's identity $$x^4+4 = (x^4+4x^2+4)-(4x^2)=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2= (x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say that you have not been able to see a patterm
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{(n^2-\frac 12)}{(n^4+\frac 14)}$$ generates the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{2}{5},\frac{8}{13},\frac{18}{25},\frac{32}{41},\frac{50}{61},\cdots\right\}$$ The numerators seem to be $2p^2$.

Now, subtract $1$ from each denominator to have
$$\left\{4,12,24,40,60,\cdots\right\}$$ which seem to be $2p(p+1)$.

So, if I am not wrong
$$S_p=\frac{2p^2}{2p(p+1)+1}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, idk why I was missing this...any other approach other than observation?

Comment: @user807908. Taking into you constraints, I do not see. Moreover, I reacted to the fact that you said that you did not find any pattern.