# How do we simplify $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^2-\frac{1}{2}}{k^4+\frac{1}{4}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How do we simplify the following sigma series? This is a JEE Advanced Level Question.

> **Problem.** Evaluate $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^2-\frac{1}{2}}{k^4+\frac{1}{4}}$$

Kindly excuse me as this is my first post here.

After a point when I have used the Sophie Germaine identity for the denominator, I am still not able to use partial fractions to express the numerator in terms of the denominator. Kindly give me a hint or explanation as to how I can simplify or explain the working/method the book's solution is saying?

[Book's Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o94vk.png)

Thanking you in advanced,
Regards.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Kindly excuse me this time please?

Comment: Hint: $$k^{4}+1/4=(k^2+k+1/2)(k^2-k+1/2)$$

Comment: I did this. But how to write the numerator in terms of the deno? to form a telescoping series? and could you please explain the Books Solution please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{20}\frac{(n^2-1/2)}{(n^4+1/4)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755408/find-the-sum-sum-n-120-fracn2-1-2n41-4)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/469239/1157207, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1573227p9671493

Answer (score 2):

Using the long way
$$\dfrac{k^2-\frac12}{k^4+\frac14}=\frac{k^2-\frac{1}{2}}{\left(k^2-k+\frac{1}{2}\right)
   \left(k^2+k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
$$\dfrac{k^2-\frac12}{k^4+\frac14}=\frac{2 k-1}{2 k^2-2 k+1}-\frac{2 k+1}{2 k^2+2 k+1}$$
$$\frac{2 k-1}{2 k^2-2 k+1}=\frac{2 a-1}{2 (a-b) (k-a)}-\frac{2 b-1}{2 (a-b) (k-b)}$$

$$\frac{2 k+1}{2 k^2+2 k+1}=\frac{2 c+1}{2 (c-d) (k-c)}-\frac{2 d+1}{2 (c-d) (k-d)}$$

where
$$(a,b)=\frac {1\pm i} 2 \qquad \text{and}\qquad (c,d)=-\frac {1\pm i} 2 $$

Now, you should see the telescoping since, by the end,
$$\dfrac{k^2-\frac12}{k^4+\frac14}=\frac{1}{2 k-(1+i)}+\frac{1}{2 k-(1-i)}-\frac{1}{2 k+(1-i)}-\frac{1}{2 k+(1+i)}$$

Answer (score 1):

The first few steps are the same as Claude
Leibovici's, but you don't need to involve complex numbers here: $$\frac{k²-\frac{1}2}{k⁴+\frac{1}4}=\frac{(2k-1)(2k+1)}{(2k²+2k+1)(2k²-2k+1)}$$
$$\frac{k²-\frac{1}2}{k⁴+\frac{1}4}=\frac{1}2(\frac{2k-1}{2k²-2k+1}-\frac{2k+1}{2k²+2k+1})$$
You'll find that the latter term can be found just by replacing $k$ by $k+1$ in the former, after which you can solve by putting $n$ in the latter term and $1$ in the former (I'll assume you are familiar with that since you are preparing for JEE Advanced. It's pretty easy to prove.)